# Build an Installer including mysql connector C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, installation

Almost done with this game that I am working on and we half to submit it for a competition. The problem is that it wont work at all without having the mysql connector with it. I was wondering how could I go about creating an installer with Visual Studio, and all my game files. Any help is appreciated. Also is there anything special to include XNA libraries too?

Answer (score 0):

The VS2010 has InstallShield LE and Setup Project project types available to you. Those projects help you make use of the Windows Installer. As far as I know windows installer doesn't let you install things for X-Box or for Windows Mobile. I assume you write for X-Box since you are using XNA. The Windows Installer lets you install to things for Windows and Windows Server.

Comment: No actually just doing a PC game with XNA. But this helped alot.